# Nodejs Express HTTPS with AWS SSL Certificate

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, express, ssl-certificate

I have purchased SSL certificate from aws certificate manager. I have a node microapplication running on an EC2 which uses that SSL through a Load Balancer.

I want to use node from an SSL url, hence will need the cert files to setup SSL in express. Unfortunatly AWS console does not have a panel to download cert files from aws console.

I am using port 8000 and that's open in the security group inbound rule.

How can I proceed further in this situation?

Comment: "will need the cert files to setup SSL in express" that's not how the AWS ACM service works. You attach the certificate to either a load balancer or CloudFront distribution that sits in front of your application.

Comment: I have attached the SSL to load balancer and the php website works perfectly. But the node does not work on https. How can I get node working then?